# When underfilling a vbox, leave all the space at the bottom

Tags: spacing

I have a XeLaTeX document in which it is easy to underfill some vboxes. This is ok for me, as long as the extra space is left at the bottom of the page (by default it is distributed between the boxes in the page). How can I instruct XeLaTeX to do that?

Comment: Wild guess: `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Sorry, apparently that was trivial...